# Adding the same month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum the quantities based on the same month . i have already done the query for adding them but the problem is that it only add the same month with the same date . this is my query for this for the month of august .

```
SELECT 
    [Purchased Product], 
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, [Purchased Quantity])) AS [Purchased Quantity],
    [Purchased Date]
FROM  
    StudentPurchasedHistoryTable
WHERE 
    DATENAME(month, [Purchased Date]) = 'August' 
GROUP BY 
    [Purchased Product], [Purchased Date]
```

It display this:

```
Purchased Product   Purchased Quantity  Purchased Date
Zesto               1                   2015-08-03 20:03:00.000
Zesto               10                  2015-08-08 00:00:00.000
Zesto               1                   2015-08-09 19:47:00.000
Mineral Water       1                   2015-08-09 19:48:00.000
Mineral Water       1                   2015-08-09 19:49:00.000
```

This is my query for displaying the name of the month only.

```
SELECT 
    [Purchased Product], 
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, [Purchased Quantity])) AS [Purchased Quantity],
    DATENAME(MONTH, [Purchased Date]) AS [Purchased Date]
FROM
    StudentPurchasedHistoryTable
WHERE 
    DATENAME(MONTH, [Purchased Date]) = 'August'
GROUP BY
    [Purchased Product], [Purchased Date]
```

This is what it display

```
Purchased Product   Purchased Quantity  Purchased Date
Zesto                1                  August
Zesto                10                 August
Zesto                1                  August
Mineral Water        1                  August
Mineral Water        1                  August
```

How can sum the purchase quantity with the same month regardless of day and time during a particular month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are selecting only one month, remove the date from the `group by` or aggregate by the monthname:

```
SELECT [Purchased Product], sum(CONVERT(INT, [Purchased Quantity])) as [Purchased Quantity],
       datename(month, [Purchased Date])  AS [Purchased Date]
from StudentPurchasedHistoryTable
WHERE DATENAME(month, [Purchased Date]) = 'August'
group by [Purchased Product], datename(month, [Purchased Date]);
```

I don't recommend naming expressions in the `select` after columns already in the data.  It can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Every year has an August so when you want to group by month, you actually want to group it by month and year. It would suck to have August 2014 mixed with August 2015.

Try this:

```
SELECT  [Purchased Product], 
        [Purchased Quantity] = sum(CONVERT(INT,[Purchased Quantity]))
        [Purchased Month]    = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY([Purchased Date]), [Purchased Date])
from    StudentPurchasedHistoryTable
WHERE   DATENAME(month, [Purchased Date]) = 'August'
group by [Purchased Product], DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY([Purchased Date]), [Purchased Date])
```